# Ways to scroll an index that takes on different values at another index in CPLEX

Tags: constraints, cplex

I have a problem in CPLEX: I have two index i and j. For each j, i is different.
When I write the constraints, how can I make it clear that for j=1, the index i goes from 1 to 10 while for j=2 the index i goes from 1 to 3 and for j=3 i goes from 1 to 7?

For example:

int num_j=...; range J=1..num_j;
int num_i=...; range I=1..num_i;

forall (i in I) // where in I there must be the different values for each J

```
 forall (j in J)
 
constraint 1: sum(m in M) y[i][j][m] == 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At array variable indexer size - 3 ways : union , tuple set, decision expression within [Making Optimization Simple](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-decision-optimization-simple-alex-fleischer/)

I gave 3 ways do deal with that challenge.

With your data

```
int num_j=3; 
range J=1..num_j;

int num_i[J]=[10,3,7]; 

range M=1..1;
range I=1..max(j in J) num_i[j];

dvar boolean y[I][J][M];
 
subject to
{


 forall (j in J)
   forall (i in 1..num_i[j]) // where in I there must be the different values for each J
 
 sum(m in M) y[i][j][m] == 1;

}
```

works fine

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help you are giving me on CPLEX.